# Unable to access LastViewedDate on Account object

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to get the list of last 5 accounts viewed. The code seems to be working in sandbox and workbench but when I try deploying it in production, I get the error: **No such column 'LastViewedDate' on entity 'Account'.**

Code:

```
 public List<Account> getAccounts(){  
         return [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC limit 5 ];  
       }
```

The class I am trying to deploy is in Version 34, the latest one.

I know this issue has been discussed before but I can't seem to find the resolution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! An alternate way to query this can be:

public List getAccounts(){
     return [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account limit 5 FOR VIEW ];
   }

This works perfectly!!

Comment: how do you order by time ?

Comment: This will not work. That query will SET the LastViewedDate to now, which in turn obviously makes those records the 5 most recently viewed records. But they weren't the most recently viewed records BEFORE we run that query. Is that what you want?

Comment: The answer listed worked for me.

Comment: But it won't get you the list of 5 last viewed records? So how does it work for you, exactly? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-standing, reported Known Issue that will finally be fixed with the [Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353660&type=1&mode=1) critical update on or before Aug 12, 2020.